# URL rewrite breaking pagination

Tags: pagination, rewrite-rules

I have been reading around and cannot seem to figure this out.

Everything is working fine except that pagination seems to not work, I am adding a second rewrite rule, shouldn't this fix that?

I can get to the first page fine, but any page beyond throws a 404.

Here is my code:

```
// Rewrite the Sermon URL
function sermon_rewrite() {
    $cpt = 'sermon';
    $tax = 'series';

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^'.$cpt.'/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?post_type='.$cpt.'&'.$tax.'=$matches[1]&'.$tax.'=$matches[2]&'.$cpt.'=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'sermon/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$',
        'index.php?post_type='.$cpt.'&'.$tax.'=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init','sermon_rewrite');
```

**EDIT**

If I go to the following url

This works: mysite.com/sermon/term/childterm/page2/

This does not: mysite.com/sermon/term/childterm/page2/

Any idea what is causing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had everything right, it just was not being called in the proper order. I should have been matching paged url's first before the post.

This is my working code:

```
// Rewrite the Sermon URL
function sermon_rewrite() {
    $cpt = 'sermon';
    $tax = 'series';

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^'.$cpt.'/([^/]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?post_type='.$cpt.'&'.$tax.'=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
        'top'
    );
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^'.$cpt.'/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?post_type='.$cpt.'&'.$tax.'=$matches[1]&'.$tax.'=$matches[2]&'.$cpt.'=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init','sermon_rewrite');
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:    **mysite.com/sermon/term/childterm/page2/**

This does not: **mysite.com/sermon/term/childterm/page2/**

---

according to your rewrite rule, I guess what you mean is

This works:    **mysite.com/sermon/term/page2/**

This does not: **mysite.com/sermon/term/childterm/page2/**

I'm not a regex expert so I only come up with **adding another rewrite rule** to handle the
childterm situaion

```
add_rewrite_rule(
        'sermon/(.*?)/(.*?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$',
        'index.php?post_type='.$cpt.'&'.$tax.'=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]',
        'top'
    );
```